# Why do permutation importances for my model all zeros?

Tags: python, boosting, importance

I really am at a loss here. I have several tree-based binary classification models trained on a balanced dataset of ~300 samples and ~15000 features. The models have AUROC around 0.8.

I want to retrieve feature importances. I have used the `permutation_importance` from sklearn, and another function self-made, all return the same values: all zeros except one single feature which has a low value. For other, non tree-based models, everything works fine and feature importances are consistent.

Basically, I have a model that is so robust and redundant that no single feature, when shuffled, is able to change the predictions.

Do I have another option than using the built-in `_feature_importances` coming from the tree structure, or SHAP values? If I am doing that, how do I compare these with the ones coming from the permutations?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say that for non-tree models the "feature importances are consistent"? Consistent with what?  \\ I wonder to what extent the importance results reflect your model having a single predictive feature. One way to investigate this would be to use [tag:boruta], which is a feature selection strategy that only retains features which are consistently better than randomized features.

Comment: I mean that some SVM, logistic, etc. models trained on the same dataset, and with similar performance, return values for all features. The values are very similar between the sklearn implementation and my own, they make sense, and they are mostly similar between models (but not always, that is the interesting bit).
So I am positive there is nothing wrong with this dataset, which I am working with for more than a year now. It's not just one model, it's all the tree-based ones. It's not just all zeros as a few features have very low values.